# how to check file writable on FTP server from java

Tags: java, ftp, fileinputstream, ftp-client

I am able to connect Ftp server. My requirement is to check if the path that will be shown after login into the server is writable in the ftp server. 
Below code is not checking `File remotefile = new File(pwd)`

```
public StringBuffer verifyMath(String host, String uname, String password, String cType){
    String MathString = "FTPHost:[" + host + "];uname[" + uname + "];cType[" + cType + "]";
    StringBuffer mBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

    try {
        client.connect(host);
        boolean login = client.login(uname, password);
        client.getReplyCode(); //230
        if (login == true) {
            log.debug("Connection established...");

            String pwd = client.printWorkingDirectory();
            File remotefile = new File(pwd);
            boolean rmtfile = remotefile.canWrite();
            boolean rmtdir = remotefile.isDirectory();

            if(!(remotefile.isDirectory() && remotefile.canWrite())) {
                mBuffer.append(MathLogger.raiseError(MathString, "Math is not Writable"));
            }           

            boolean logout = client.logout();
            if (logout) {
                log.debug("Connection close...");
            }
        } else {
            mBuffer.append(MathLogger.raiseError(MathString, "Connection failed."));
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        mBuffer.append(MathLogger.raiseError(MathString, e));
    } finally {
        try {
            client.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return mBuffer;
}
```

Comment: try to upload something and see what happens. There's no support in the FTP protocol for getting read/writeable status. All you can do is try and see if it succeeds/fails.

Comment: that is restricted. because there are some triggers which will cause issues to other systems when a file is placed on ftp server

Comment: Can you write some sort of webservice running on the FTP host that can return the write status of the file? As MarcB said, native FTP doesn't transmit that information.

Comment: No, I am not supposed to touch or host any service on FTP server based on my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mlistFile](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#mlistFile%28java.lang.String%29) (or possibly mlistDir) is probably the API you are looking for to call on the remote directory.  That returns an [FTPFile](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPFile.html) object that has the permission info.  Of course these will only work if the FTP server supports [RFC 3659](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3659) extensions.

So something like:

```
FTPFile remoteDir = client.mlistFile(client.printWorkingDirectory());
if (remoteDir.hasPermission(FTPFile.USER_ACCESS,FTPFile.WRITE_PERMISSION)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I have the Apache commons API but mlistFile() is not appearing on the FTPClient instance when typed

Comment: I'd check for an old version of Apache Commons Net.  According to the docs it's been there since 3.0, which is from May 2011.

Comment: thanks, I changed version of it to 3.0 and got the method mlistFile(). but remoteDir is returning null? client.printWorkingDirectory() is returning the path like  /home1/fdlqa302/cprg/mahts/mergereR/fromGIRAR

Comment: I have listed all files on the directory being verified for writable and then used the method permission then it is working.